# Is there a cleaner way to save object to db than to declare props one by one like this:

Tags: django

How does this code look like to you? In html I have fields with name properties and I refer those
names here. I just made this up myself havent seen similar examples.

```
def addsupplier(request):
    a = request.POST['companyname']
    b = request.POST['contactname']
    c = request.POST['address']
    d = request.POST['phone']
    e = request.POST['email']
    f = request.POST['country']
    Supplier(companyname = a, contactname = b, address = c, phone = d, email = e, country = f).save()
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

Comment: Do you know about [Django's ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)? Any reason not to use them?

Comment: I didnt know. These anwers helped me. I have no reason not to use them. I guess I can make several forms for get if I want to apply filtering with varying conditions for example.

Comment: Or is this for get type of things at all?

Answer (score 2):

A more cleaner way is to use django ModelForms

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Supplier
class SupplierForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = '__all__' #or put the fields you want in list


def addsupplier(request):
    form = SupplierForm(request.POST or None)
    if(form.is_valid()):
        form.save() 
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    else:
        return render(request, 'template', context)
```